# Merging 2 sorted arrays into a new sorted one does not work. What am i doing wrong?

Tags: c, sorting, merge

This function merges sorted1 and sorted2 into a new sorted array (result).
90% of the time this function works fine, but sometimes though 1-2 numbers are not where they should be (most of the time these numbers are the last ones).

Can anybody help me find what am i doing wrong?

```
void merge2(int *sorted1,int *sorted2,int *result,int K)
{   
    int i,j,k;
    i=j=k=0;

    while(i<K && j<K)
    {
        if(*(sorted1+i)>*(sorted2+j))
        {
            *(result+k)=*(sorted2+j);
            j++;
            k++;
            if(*(sorted1+i)<*(sorted2+j))
            {
                *(result+k)=*(sorted1+i);
                i++;
                k++;
            }
        }   
        else if(*(sorted1+i)<*(sorted2+j))
        {
            *(result+k)=*(sorted1+i);
            i++;
            k++;
            if(*(sorted1+i)>*(sorted2+j))
            {
                *(result+k)=*(sorted2+j);
                j++;
                k++;
            }                
        }
        else
        {
            *(result+k)=*(sorted1+i);
            k++;
            i++;
            *(result+k)=*(sorted2+j);
            k++;
            j++;
        }  
    }

    while(i<K)
    {
        *(result+k)=*(sorted1+i);
        i++;
        k++;
    }

    while(j<K)
    {
        *(result+k)=*(sorted1+j);
        j++;
        k++;
    }        
}
```

Comment: I haven't received it much, but your nested if statements look like they might smell funny. You should probably just walk through the code in your debugger though.

Comment: What is an example of two sorted lists that result in an improperly sorted result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use i as the counter for sorted1, and j as the counter for sorted2. When i reaches K the bottom while loop should fill the rest of result with the remaining elements of sorted2, however you fill it with elements from sorted1. This means no matter which counter hits K first, you fill with sorted1 for the rest, so the fix for this is:

```
while(j<K)
{
    *(result+k)=*(sorted2+j);  // This used to be sorted1
    j++;
    k++;
}
```

You mention that errors are at the end *most of the time*, which implies there are other errors as well. If you could supply a data set where this is the case (the error is not at the end) I will amend my answer with a fix for that (given I can find it).

Note that the innermost branches aren't strictly necessary. Pseudocode of what your first loop is doing:

```
1    if sorted1[i] > sorted2[j]:
2        result[k++] = sorted2[j++]
3        if sorted1[i] < sorted2[j]:
4            result[k++] = sorted1[i++] 
5    else if sorted1[i] < sorted2[j]:
6        result[k++] = sorted1[i++]
7        if sorted1[i] Z sorted2[j]:
8            result[k++] = sorted1[i++]
9    else
10       result[k++] = sorted1[i++]
11       result[k++] = sorted2[j++]
```

Lines 3 and 4 do the same thing as lines 5 ands 6 do the next loop iteration, and equivalently lines 7 and 8 do what 1 and 2 do. You can reduce it to doing:

```
1    if sorted1[i] > sorted2[j]:
2        result[k++] = sorted2[j++]
3    else if sorted1[i] < sorted2[j]:
4        result[k++] = sorted1[i++]
5    else
6        result[k++] = sorted1[i++]
7        result[k++] = sorted2[j++]
```

Edit: Finally, note that by comparing both i and j with K, your merge algorithm works exclusively if sorted1 and sorted2 that are both K elements long. I assume this is by design in my answer, but for a more general solution, pass in sizes of both arrays and compare i and j with their respective counterparts.